# Laptop "Speed" Modes

Tags: laptop, speed, function-keys, fn-key

So I have this SamSung Laptop that I've had for awhile and have never messed with the Fn F1-F9 buttons. So I was going through to see what each one of them did and ran across what I'm Assuming is "Speed Modes". It includes "Silent Mode", "Normal Mode", "Speed Mode" and "Speed Boot"

What are these and what does each one do? If I'm running Starcraft II on this laptop should I run in Speed Mode or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speed Mode and the other modes are not really overclocking it sounds like. It's more of an affinity and resource priority shortcut. For example, if you're running two applications that are both taxing your memory and processor, but keeping one application focused and hitting FN F8, you can give priority to resources to that application. It could potentially speed up your experience in Starcraft, but I would not expect huge gains. The game will still most likely be limited to the GPU you have onboard the laptop.

http://www.electricpig.co.uk/how-to-make-the-most-of-samsung-easy-speedup-manager/